# How to create ListView element with changing values?

Tags: android, android-listview

See the image below. For the first item it shows value *1:25 - 2:45* for a few seconds, then changes it (scrolls to) *2:10 - 5:00*, then back to *1:25 - 2:45* and so on.
How to implement the same on Android?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to create a custom `View` that takes in the information that you want and scrolls through it on its own.  Then you can load all the data in and just let it go.

Comment: Is there any example of such View?

Comment: No, because you haven't written it yet! ;)  There is no standard view that will do this for you so you'll need to start from scratch.  This webpage is a good place to start.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: Ok, probably I can use TextSwitcher instead?

Comment: That could work as a base class, but you'd need to add in a timer if you want it to be automatic.

Comment: And, if I implement custom View, how can I implement automatic periodic text change? In which method?

Comment: Same way.  You could create a class that was a subclass of TextSwitcher and then you could pass in a time delay and start a timer to switch the text based on that.

Comment: @CaseyB, this is something absolutely new for me. I understand the idea, but can not understand where exactly timer should be added. Could you please refer me to some example? Thanks.